# ASP.NET Identity DBContext or Site DB Context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been kind of out of the .net game for a while and I wanted to try the different new technologies.

I set up a site that uses code first migrations with EF 6 and MVC. The DBContext is created in my DAL and I'm using a repository / unit of work / n-tier implementation. I've created a ***User*** entity that holds profile information and a DBContext, let's call it **SiteDbContext**.

Now I'm at the MVC part and I'm trying to figure out the ASP.NET Identity. I have a few questions:

1) Should I use the **ApplicationDBContext** created in the UI along with **SiteDbContext** or dispose the **ApplicationDBContext** and use **SiteDbContext** (and just make sure it inherits *IdentityDbContext*)?

2) If I use the same DBContext, will it be a problem if I create a dependency on the asp.net identity in my DAL layer? Entity Layer (for ApplicationUser)? I don't want to create a dependency on my DAL regarding the DBContext so how would I supply it to the OwinContext?

3) I would like to use different DBContexts but I'm wondering how I'd make navigation properties to my User to the ASP.NET Identity user, vice versa etc.

Are there example projects I can download that implement multiple DBContexts or combine preexisting DBContexts with the ApplicationDBContext?

Thanks!

Eitan